# Using integration to find displacement of on object given points and velocity function

Tags: calculus, integration

My problem:

> Find the displacement of an object from $t=2$ to $t=3$. If the velocity of the object at time $t$ is given by $$v= \frac{t^2 + 1}{(t^3 + 3t)^2}$$

I would like to know the step by step way of integrating this V function because i have tried and the answer I get is 1/12(1/u^-3) which i don't think is the appropriate answer. Anyone willing can assist, I will really appreciate.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You problem can be expressed as the following integral.
$$
\int_2^3 v(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
$$
This integral can be simplified by performing the substitution $u=t^3+3t$ with $\mathrm{d}u = (3t^3+3)\mathrm{d}x$:

\begin{align}
\int_2^3 v(t) \, \mathrm{d}t &= \int_2^3 \!\frac{t^2 + 1}{(t^3 + 3t)^2}\, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{3} \int_2^3 \!\frac{3t^2 + 3}{(t^3 + 3t)^2}\, \mathrm{d}t \\ &= \frac{1}{3}\int_{14}^{36} \!\frac{1}{u^2}\, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{3}\left[-u^{-1} \right]_{14}^{36} = \frac{1}{3}\left[-\frac{1}{36} + \frac{1}{14}\right] \\ &=\frac{11}{756}.
\end{align}

This evaluation is confirmed by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+2+to+3+(t%5E2+%2B+1)%2F(t%5E3+%2B+3t)%5E2).

Comment: Thanks Brian. But would you mind giving the step by step solution for intergration of this funtion v

Comment: @CollinsSoiSnr Could you be more specific about what step in my answer is unclear to you?

Comment: How you intergrated  3t^2 +3/ (t^3+ 3t)^2 to 1/u^2 letting u be t^3 + 3t

Comment: @CollinsSoiSnr That is a [substitution](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SubstitutionRuleIndefinite.aspx). You can think of it as the chain rule for differentiation in reverse. In short, $$\int_a^b f(g(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u) \, \mathrm{d}u$$ where $u=g(x)$.